# Prometheus Alertmanager Cluster mode sending duplicate alerts

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have a monitoring system using 2 EC2 instances, each running prom/prometheus:v2.30.0 and prom/alertmanager:v0.23.0 and both of the prometheus instances are **scraping** the same metrics sending the alerts to both alertmanagers:

```
# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
       - targets:
           - rms-a:9093
           - rms-b:9093
```

This is what appears in the status window in the alertmanager:

```
Cluster Status
Name:
01FG7G4CEZY8CZJYPWH5BSF25B
Status: ready
Peers:
Name: 01FG7G4CEZY8CZJYPWH5BSF25B
Address: <IP A>:9094
Name: 01FG7G4DTK7YEW1WG78M7AMTQZ
Address: <IP B>:9094
```

I start the alertmanager with this configuration in both servers:

```
alertmanager:
  container_name: alertmanager
  image: prom/alertmanager:v0.23.0
  ports:
    - '9093:9093'
    - '9094:9094'
  volumes:
    - "./alertmanager/alertmanager.yml:/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml"
  command:
    - "--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml"
    - "--storage.path=/alertmanager"
    - "--cluster.peer=${PEER}:9094"
    - "--cluster.listen-address=:9094"
    - "--cluster.advertise-address=${PUBLIC_IP}:9094"
    - "--cluster.gossip-interval=200ms"
    - "--cluster.pushpull-interval=1m0s"
```

Note: PEER will have the value of the other instance and PUBLIC_IP the public IP of the EC2 Instance where it's running.

When I look into the alerts, they are exactly equal, except one field "**replica**" that has both values, A and B representing it was send by both instances and this produces 2 alerts about the same thing. I was expecting only one alert.

What can I do to fix my configuration? Is there any hints on this?